# Is there a work around to avoid using TRUNC(Date) in sql in order to get benefit from indexes?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `BOOKING_DETAILS` which `DEFINITE_DATE` is a column with 'DATE' type. (DB is Oracle 12 c). also, `DEFINITE_DATE` column is indexed. I want the following query to optimize in order to use the index created for `DEFINITE_DATE`.

How can I do that?

```
select * 
  from BOOKING_DETAILS 
 where trunc(DEFINITE_DATE) = trunc(TO_DATE('2018-10-26', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `trunc(TO_DATE('2018-10-26','YYYY-MM-DD'))` can be simplified to `TO_DATE('2018-10-26','YYYY-MM-DD')` or even `date '2018-10-26'`

Comment: I like this question. Often proposed solutions suggest using functions on database fields but they forget to mention you loose the use of indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a between condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select *
from BOOKING_DETAILS 
where DEFINITE_DATE >= date '2018-10-26' and
      DEFINITE_DATE < date '2018-10-27';
```

This would return all records where the definite date falls on 26-October-2018 proper.  The above `WHERE` clause is *sargable*, because it allows Oracle to use an index on `DEFINITE_DATE`, should it exist.

Comment: Using `date` for date constants is much cleaner than `to_date()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create index on `trunc(DEFINITE_DATE)` and use existing query, you can

```
select * 
  from BOOKING_DETAILS 
 where DEFINITE_DATE >= TO_DATE('2018-10-26', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
   and DEFINITE_DATE < TO_DATE('2018-10-26', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks, @Dmitry