# Please, my Oracle EBS query when creating a custom report still contains duplicate data,

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, oraclereports, oracle-ebs

```
SELECT
    MMT.TRANSACTION_DATE TANGGAL
    , HCA.ACCOUNT_NUMBER NIK
    , AC.CUSTOMER_NAME NAMA_SALES
    , RCTLA.INTERFACE_LINE_ATTRIBUTE1||'.'||RCTLA.INTERFACE_LINE_ATTRIBUTE2 NOMOR_RETUR
    , CASE 
        WHEN MTT.TRANSACTION_TYPE_NAME IN ('FPPR Kembali BS') 
        THEN 'Retur Unit Rokok BS'
        WHEN MTT.TRANSACTION_TYPE_NAME IN ('FPPR Kembali GS', 'RMA Receipt') 
        THEN 'Retur Unit Rokok Bagus'
        WHEN MTT.TRANSACTION_TYPE_NAME IN ('FPPR Retur Beli Receipt')
        THEN 'Retur Customer Potong Setoran'
        ELSE MTT.TRANSACTION_TYPE_NAME
    END JENIS_RETUR
    , XCRIV.CROSS_REFERENCE JENIS_ROKOK
FROM MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS MMT
    , HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS HCA
    , AR_CUSTOMERS AC
    , RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL RCTA
    , RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_LINES_ALL RCTLA
    , MTL_TRANSACTION_TYPES MTT
    , XTD_CROSS_REFF_ITEM_V XCRIV
    , OE_ORDER_LINES_ALL OOLA
    , oe_order_headers_all OOHA
    , MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B MSIB
    , HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS HOU
WHERE 1=1
    AND MMT.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID = MTT.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID
    AND MMT.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = XCRIV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID 
    AND MMT.ORGANIZATION_ID = XCRIV.ORGANIZATION_ID
    AND MMT.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = MSIB.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
    AND MMT.ORGANIZATION_ID = MSIB.ORGANIZATION_ID
    and ooha.header_id=oola.header_id
    and ooha.sold_to_org_id=hca.cust_account_id
    and hca.cust_account_id=ac.customer_id
    and msib.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=oola.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
    and msib.ORGANIZATION_ID=oola.SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID
    and rcta.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = rctla.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID
    and rctla.interface_line_attribute1 = to_char(ooha.ORDER_NUMBER)
    AND HOU.ORGANIZATION_ID = OOLA.SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID
    -- HARDCODE
    AND HCA.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 'HOQSD00001'
    AND TRUNC(MMT.TRANSACTION_DATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(TO_DATE(:P_DATE_FROM, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')) AND TRUNC(TO_DATE(:P_DATE_TO, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'))
    AND XCRIV.CROSS_REFERENCE = 'ARB16'
```

Please, my Oracle EBS query when creating a custom report still contains duplicate data, in my opinion I have done a JOIN for all the relationship IDs but why are they still duplicated? Have I missed the ID that should have been JOIN'd?

please help me to solve my problem

Comment: I have no idea, I don't use EBS. The simplest option is to include `SELECT DISTINCT` which might, or might not help. On the other hand, if performance *sucks* anyway, that won't solve anything. I'd suggest you to start over, going step-by-step, adding table-by-table into FROM clause, applying correct JOINs and filters (WHERE conditions) until you find the culprit and fix what's wrong.

Comment: Add the ID columns for each of the tables to the SELECT statement. That should allow you see which rows are repeated. Also, rewrite the join condition to remove the TRUNC on the MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_DATE column. It will prevent the use of any indexes on that column. See [Is there a work around to avoid using TRUNC(Date) in sql in order to get benefit from indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249727/is-there-a-work-around-to-avoid-using-truncdate-in-sql-in-order-to-get-benefit)